# An efficient way to find a postdoc for an operations researcher

Tags: machine-learning

Disclaimer: I am not sure if this is the right forum to ask this question.

I am looking for a postdoc position in operations research in the US. So far, I have found three ways:

- INFORMS community (or some other similar websites) includes some positions but it does not cover the majority of them.
- Some of the positions are advertised on the university's website, some positions are posted on the department's website, some are posted on LinkedIn, etc. It is confusing and difficult to find the postings.
- Send a direct email to professors with similar research interests. This method is extensively time-consuming and a bit unethical to reject a professor when they show interest.

I was wondering what would be the most efficient strategy that you recommend to an operations researcher to find a post-doc (or even a professorship) position in the US. Please note that my research interests include: (i) healthcare and supply chain management, and (ii) applications of operations research and machine learning methods. However willing to work in other related areas.

Comment: I don't see what's even a bit unethical about contacting a professor, and not accepting a postdoc with them if you don't reach mutually agreeable terms. Same as for any other job, or graduate school admissions, etc.

Comment: https://academicpositions.com/ and https://www.euro-online.org/bb/#/forum/2 (Euro optimisationjobs) -- also, subscribe to DMANET (https://www.zaik.uni-koeln.de/mailman/listinfo/dmanet) -- As far as I know, postdocs are paid and treated better outside the US than in the US (but this is an entirely different conversation).

Comment: My advice- If you did your PhD in the US, then go to Europe or Asia or Australia for your postdoc -- it really opens your eyes to the wider world.. I did my PhD in the US and went to Australia for my postdoc, then worked in Europe and Asia - I am glad that I took the decision to leave the US after PhD.

Answer (score 1):

Most postings will be public and will show up based on recency and click rate. You can start in google with an efficient search string like postdoc+PhD+operations research|data science or postdoctoral+PhD+operations research.
Also search Insidehighered careers page.